# Which IAM role do I need to be able to do kubectl into GKE clusters in GCP?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, google-cloud-iam

I need to be able to do *kubectl* into our GKE clusters. But it seems I don't have the necessary permissions.

I first tried to initiate connection to our GKE using this command:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials my_gke_cluster --region=us-east4 --project=my_gcp_project
```

Then I ran

```
kubectl get namespace
```

It won't work. I do not likely have the necessary permissions.

Which bare minimum IAM role do I need? My end goal is to be able to run *kubectl* and access the pod logs through command line. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum role you need to be able to kubectl objects is:

```
roles/container.viewer (Kubernetes Engine Viewer)
```

To get logs you need this role:

```
roles/container.developer (Kubernetes Engine Developer)
```